# How to set anycharts stock scroller to not move size

Tags: anychart

I have a function on a js to create an anychart.stock

```
dataTable = anychart.data.table();
dataTable.addData(json);

price = dataTable.mapAs({'value': 1});  
height = dataTable.mapAs({'value': 2});
weight = dataTable.mapAs({'value': 3});

var pricesChart= chart.plot(0);
    pricesChart.grid().enabled(true);
    pricesChart.grid(1).enabled(true).layout('vertical');
PricePlot = pricesChart.stepLine(price).stroke('#004400');


var heightChart= chart.plot(0);
        heightChart.grid().enabled(true);
        heightChart.grid(1).enabled(true).layout('vertical');
    heightPlot = heightChart.stepLine(height).stroke('#334400');

var weightChart= chart.plot(0);
        weightChart.grid().enabled(true);
        weightChart.grid(1).enabled(true).layout('vertical');
    weightPlot = weightChart.stepLine(weight).stroke('#334400');
```

When the plot is displayed all the scales can be seen OK. See this image:
[image]

**The problem appears when** I move the scroll to the right. It modifies the scale of my last chart causing this chart to be unreadable. See next image:
[image]

Comment: do you want the dimensions (min and max) of the scale to stay the same no matter what the data is on the chart?

Comment: I would like the dimensions to be modify depending on the data to be display.

Comment: As a default, linear y-scale auto calculates its min/max value according to available data. Unfortunately, your screenshots don't provide information about the data on the plot. Please, can you provide us the full screenshot (all the data should be visible) of the last plot before and after scrolling? This will help us to analyze the problem and provide a solution.

Comment: I'll try to replicate the chart with other data since I am under a privacy policy for the data. (Reason why I did not put all the chart or the data)

Comment: Sure! We understand that. Your sample with dummy data will help us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned what happened to the visualization.

The problem is that given a period of time, for example, this year from 01-01-2019 to 31-12-2019 I am using three different lines to display information.

The first line contains info from 01-01-2019 to today
The second line contains info from today to 7 days ahead
The third period contains info from 7 days ahead to 31-12-2019.

The fact that the lines are not continuous is what is breaking the zoom.